# Is there any way to get the offset of the record in the mysql resultset ?

Tags: mysql

There is a mysql query.

suppose :
select primary_field, field2 from mytable order by field2

field2 is not unique.

now in the result if i have a record having values ( 536, any_value ).

I want to get the offset (position of the record in the result) .

infact i need it to get the next and previous record of the current record.

i dont want to fetch all records and then process it in php to get next and previous record.

i want to get it done in mysql query. is it possible in mysql query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes and no. If you have the result, then it may not be possible to retrieve the specific row if it is non-unique. But, if you simply want to get the row number:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, t.* 
   from my_table t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by field2;
```

Oh, and [credit where credit is due](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/).